# Paper effect with SVG feDiffuseLighting filter

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I am trying to achieve a paint-on-paper effect on shapes in SVG by applying:

- a displacement filter and
- a blur

Everything works ok on the background, but if I try to apply the same filter to shapes in the foreground, it results in a weird border around the shape itself, that gets even worse if the shape is a path.

[This](https://codepen.io/simonecesano/pen/jOqRebE) is the version without filter on the shape, [this](https://codepen.io/simonecesano/pen/abNxRzw) is the one with the filter applied to a rotated `rect` and [this](https://codepen.io/simonecesano/pen/oNxOaXE) is the version where the filter is applied to a path. BTW, the displacement and blur filters seem to work ok only in Firefox.

The code for the `rect` version is below.

Can I apply the diffuse lighting filter to the shape without the weird border?

```html
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   id="svg66"
   version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 1100.20831 1529.16669"
   height="1529.16669mm"
   width="1100.20831mm">
  <metadata
     id="metadata63">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>

  <filter id='roughpaper' x='0%' y='0%' width='100%' height="102%">
    <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.2" result='noise' numOctaves="3" />
    <feDiffuseLighting in='noise' out="paper" lighting-color='#ffffff' surfaceScale='2'>
      <feDistantLight azimuth='100' elevation='60' />
    </feDiffuseLighting>

    <feGaussianBlur in="paper" stdDeviation="1.2" result="blurredpaper"/>

    <feComponentTransfer>
      <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.7"/>
    </feComponentTransfer>    
  </filter>

  <filter id="dispmorph">
    <feMorphology radius="0" in="SourceGraphic" result="morph" />
    <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.04 0.04" numOctaves="2" result="turbulence"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="morph" out="turbuled" scale="1" xChannelSelector="B" yChannelSelector="G"/>
    <feGaussianBlur in="turbuled" stdDeviation="0.2" result="blur"/>

    <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.2" result='noise' numOctaves="3" />
    <feDiffuseLighting in='noise' out="paper" lighting-color='#ffffff' surfaceScale='2'>
      <feDistantLight azimuth='100' elevation='60' />
    </feDiffuseLighting>

    <feGaussianBlur in="paper" stdDeviation="1.2" result="blurredpaper"/>

    <feBlend in="blur" in2="blurredpaper" mode="multiply"/>

  </filter>
  <g id="layer1">
    <rect
       filter="url(#roughpaper)"      
       y="0"
       x="0"
       height="100"
       width="100"
       id="rect92"
       />
    <rect
    transform="rotate(-10 50 100)"
    id="path82"
    y="25"
    x="25"
    height="50"
    width="50"
    filter="url(#dispmorph)"      
    style="fill:#204a87;stroke:none" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Quick observation - those "out=" should be "result="

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be an interaction bug between the output of the feDisplacementMap and the feBlend. I can fix this on Chrome/Windows at least by replacing feBlend/multiply - with the equivalent feComposite/arithmetic k1=1

```html
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   id="svg66"
   version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 1100.20831 1529.16669"
   height="1529.16669mm"
   width="1100.20831mm">
  <metadata
     id="metadata63">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>

  <filter id='roughpaper' x='0%' y='0%' width='100%' height="102%">
    <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.2" result='noise' numOctaves="3" />
    <feDiffuseLighting in='noise' out="paper" lighting-color='#ffffff' surfaceScale='2'>
      <feDistantLight azimuth='100' elevation='60' />
    </feDiffuseLighting>

    <feGaussianBlur in="paper" stdDeviation="1.2" result="blurredpaper"/>

    <feComponentTransfer>
      <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.7"/>
    </feComponentTransfer>    
  </filter>

  <filter id="dispmorph">
    <feMorphology radius="0" in="SourceGraphic" result="morph" />
    <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.04 0.04" numOctaves="2" result="turbulence"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="morph" out="turbuled" scale="1" xChannelSelector="B" yChannelSelector="G"/>
    <feGaussianBlur in="turbuled" stdDeviation="0.2" result="blur"/>

    <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.2" result='noise' numOctaves="3" />
    <feDiffuseLighting in='noise' out="paper" lighting-color='#ffffff' surfaceScale='2'>
      <feDistantLight azimuth='100' elevation='60' />
    </feDiffuseLighting>

    <feGaussianBlur in="paper" stdDeviation="1.2" result="blurredpaper"/>

    <feComposite operator="arithmetic" k1="1" in="blur" in2="blurredpaper"/>

  </filter>
  <g id="layer1">
    <rect
       filter="url(#roughpaper)"      
       y="0"
       x="0"
       height="100"
       width="100"
       id="rect92"
       />
    <rect
    transform="rotate(-10 50 100)"
    id="path82"
    y="25"
    x="25"
    height="50"
    width="50"
    filter="url(#dispmorph)"      
    style="fill:#204a87;stroke:none" />
  </g>
</svg>
```